# Reputation does not update without the page refresh

Tags: feature-request, reputation

The reputations is not updating quickly  while up/down/mark votes.

Please take a look at this below images.

**Initial time :**

[image]

**After Voted :**

[image]

***So we need to do refresh the browser  to see the updated reputations*** It's not so far.

> It could be look better if we update the reputation quickly while up/down/mark votes.

**EDIT:** I think guys are misunderstand my question. Actually I am not mean by Live reputation. I am just suggest 
for increase and decrease the reputation on UI object while clicking the `up/down` vote and `mark and delete/undelete` buttons.

Comment: Refresh the page. The rep displayed there isn't "live".

Comment: Every time I need to do refresh the browser?

Comment: From the feature request wiki: _Your question should contain the details of your proposal, including a justification of why the new feature is needed and/or how it can improve the community. Basically, prove to the administration that they should spend time developing your feature._. Please add this to your request.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Did you read my question fully? *So we need to do refresh to see the updated/latest reputations in every time*

Comment: And ___please___, stop submitting feature requests and bug reports to meta. You clearly have a completely different interpretation of how SE is supposed to work, than the majority of the community. I don't get why you even bother any more.

Comment: @RameshRajendran Why is that needed? Why should they spend time developing that feature?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Is it far? if every time needs to refresh the page to see question and answers after the user is clicked on the post/create button?

Comment: I think the question is, does it really matter if the rep is refreshed? In my opinion it really doesn't matter.

Comment: @RameshRajendran Why do you need to see that updated reputation? Explain why you want to see live reputation (tip: rep after vote = rep before vote + 10 for answers, for questions it's rep + 5, quick maths). We all know a refresh wastes some time, but fetching it every time someone votes wastes server and browser resources.

Comment: Technically speaking, the reputation *is* updated quickly on the page if you press F5.

Comment: Imagine if this is the case in a crowded tag... Do you have extra RAM lying around?

Comment: So you are here to track reputation? Reputation is not the main purpose of this site, the content of question/answer is more important

Comment: I have another feature request for you : reputation on the Meta site is not updating even if you refresh, it took time to get updated with your repuation from the main site!

Comment: .... Please stop.

Answer (score 15):

That's by design.
The rep shown on the page isn't live *anywhere*.

Considering the *significant effort* and additional server load required to display *live* reputation changes for every user on the page, I'd argue that building that would be a waste of SE's time.

Comment: I think guys are misunderstand my question. Actually I am not mean by Live reputation. I am just suggest for increase and decrease the reputation on UI `object` while clicking the up/down vote and mark and delete/undelete buttons.

Comment: What if someone else votes? You see the vote count change, but the reputation stays the same. What if someone votes for a different answer elsewhere? Suddenly, you see the rep lower when you upvote... There is just way more to it than you think.

Comment: @RameshRajendran That still doesn't make the suggestion any better. Is it really that much effort to press F5? Surely it is *much* less effort as even attempting to implement the change. Implementation effort is way too big compared to the 'QoL' update it would give.

Comment: @Ramesh as in when I upvote your Q, I see your rep go up +5? Because if that's what you mean, I can foresee you coming back with a bug in about 3 days with "I upvoted this guy, saw the +5, then refreshed but it updated to another number again" (if the user gets MORE votes before you refresh)..... There is LITERALLY no value in this feature.  (btw, usual disclaimer of maybe stopping coming to meta as soon as something pops in your mind? do some research, review how it works, think further than "this would be a nice to have", THEN come to meta...)

Comment: How does it work from architecture point of view? Is it based on events and reputation is later updated after processing events?

Answer (score 5):

The point of Stack Overflow is to generate high quality questions and answers about programming. Reputation is just one of the tools used to make it happen.

That's why among the things that do update automatically without a page refresh are when new answers are posted to a question (you get the little banner that pops up to load the new answer when you're viewing a question) and when new questions are posted (if you're viewing a certain tag's newest questions).

The resources necessary to generate those updates for questions and answers are justified because they are the main purpose of the site.

Reputation is not the main purpose of the site, so an auto-update of it is not worth the resources. It is perfectly reasonable that reputation has to wait until a page refresh. I do not believe this feature request should be implemented.

Comment: Upvoting you but you reputation is not changing ... strange ... :p

Comment: @TemaniAfif Uh-oh, maybe you should make a feature request or a bug report -- or both! ;D

Comment: @DavyM bug-request?